# In Typescript, why is an Omit type not a Partial type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, partial

Consider this code:

```
interface Foo {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}

function f<T extends Foo>(x: Omit<T, "a">): void {
    g(x);
}

function g<T extends Foo>(x: Partial<T>): void {
}
```

The call to g(x) results in this compiler error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Omit<T, "a">' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<T>'.
Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<keyof T, "a">'.
Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<keyof T, "a">'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<keyof T, "a">'.
```

Why is this? AFAIK, the Omit constructs a type like T, but with the field a missing. The Partial constructs a type like T, but with arbitrary fields missing (possibly none missing). This seems to me that the Omit type should be okay for the Partial. Why not?

The following function compiles fine:

```
function h(x: {b: string, c: string}): void {
    g(x);
}
```

So either Omit does something else than I think, or the problem comes from the fact that f and g also accept any type that extends T. However, the same logic should apply whenever f and g get parameterized with the same T, and even enforcing that by changing the call to `g<T>(x);` does not change the error.

Comment: "*AFAIK, the Omit constructs a type like T, but with the field a missing. The Partial constructs a type like T, but with arbitrary fields missing (possibly none missing). This seems to me that the Omit type should be okay for the Partial.*" `Omit` means the property *should not be present*, while `Partial` means some properties *might not be present*. Not the same thing. A bicycle has two wheels only. A car with two wheels currently missing is not the same as a bicycle.

Comment: That's my point, the Omit makes sure the property is not present. The Partial doesn't care if it is present. That sounds okay to me. The analogy didn't really help me, to be honest -- it sounds like the Partial expects some totally different type (car), but they both start with the same type T. Let's say T is "car". Then Omit<T> means "must have the front left wheel missing", while Partial<T> says "may have arbitrary wheels missing". That sounds like it should work.

Comment: In a structurally typed world, if a bicycle is defined only as "has two wheels", a car with two wheels mising is a bicycle. I agree with Martin here, I would naively expect this to work as well.

Comment: "may have arbitrary wheels missing" means it might be the rear left wheel. Also, they *might* be missing but also *might* be present. `Omit` means they should never be a possibility.

Comment: @VLAZ But an object where a property is definitely missing should be assignable to a type where that property is optional; the type's contract is guaranteed to be fulfilled because "that property will never be set" satisfies "optional".

Comment: Note that if you remove the generic argument and use `Omit<Foo, "a">` and `Partial<Foo>` directly, it does work.

Comment: @VLAZ: I'm trying to pass the Omit as a Partial, not the other way round. WRT to b, that means to pass `{b: string}` as `{b?: string}`.

Comment: I tried calling g as `g<T>(x)` to make sure it doesn't infer the wrong type for G, but the error stays the same.

Comment: Funny enough, replacing `T extends Foo` with `T` for the function `f`, makes it work, which I expect, it shouldn't.